# How do we prove that two conjugate operators $X$ and $Y$ induce $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ driving terms when restricted to a two level subspace?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, two-level-system

Suppose I have a Hamiltonian for a particle moving in a one dimensional potential

$$H = H(X,Y) \qquad [X,Y] = i$$

where $X$ is the dimensionless position, $Y$ is the dimensionless momentum, and $\epsilon_0$ is an energy scale.
Both $X$ and $Y$ are Hermitian.
Now suppose we add a driving Hamiltonian

$$H_x = \epsilon_x \, f_x(t) \, X$$

where $f_x(t)$ is a dimensionless function of time and $\epsilon_x$ is another energy scale.
If $f_x(t)$ is on resonance with a transition between two energy eigenstates of $H$, we expect it to produce transitions between those two states.
Restricting considerations to just those two levels, we can write $H_x$ as a 2x2 matrix:

$$H_x \sim \epsilon_x f_x(t)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 &
\langle 0 | X | 1 \rangle \\
\langle 1 | X | 0 \rangle &
0
\end{array}
\right)
= \epsilon_x \langle 1 | X | 0 \rangle f_x(t) \sigma_x \, .
$$
where $\sim$ means "is represented by" and we've assumed $\langle 0 | X | 0 \rangle$ and $\langle 1 | X | 1 \rangle$ are both zero.$^{[a]}$

Now suppose we have a different driving Hamiltonian

$$H_y = \epsilon_y f_y(t) Y \, .$$

By similar reasoning to what we did above, we could reason that

$$H_y \sim \epsilon_y f_y(t) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \langle 0 | Y | 1 \rangle \\
\langle 1 | Y | 0 \rangle & 0
\end{array}
\right)
= \epsilon_y \langle 1 | Y | 0 \rangle f_y(t) \sigma_x \, .$$
This, however, is not correct.
By looking at examples such as the harmonic oscillator we find that the driving Hamiltonian which couples to $Y$ is proportional to $\sigma_y$, *not* $\sigma_x$.

How, in general, can we argue that two conjugate operators, when restricted to a certain two state subspace, must be proportional to $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$?

$[a]$: Or at least, we can ignore the diagonal elements of $H_x$. In general the diagonal part can be written as a sum of $\sigma_z$ and the identity. The identity part can be completely ignored. The $\sigma_z$ part can be dropped if $f(t)$ is oscillatory because is just induces a net-zero fluctuation in the level splitting between $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. I think.

Comment: Why can't they be proportional to $\sigma_z$? Note that since the Pauli matrices span the space of Hermitian operators over $\mathbb R$, *any* Hermitian operator acts as a linear combination of Paulis on a two-dimensional subspace.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Please see the footnote $[a]$.

Comment: Well, then it is clear that whatever you get must be a linear combination of $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ with real coefficients.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I can't tell whether that's begging the question or not. Would you care to write an answer? :)

Comment: Well, I don't know if I get your question right.  Is your question: "Why can the matrix elements of any hermitian operator, projected to a two-dimensional subspace, expressed in terms of the Pauli X and Y matrices (given that we know the diagonal is zero)?"

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: No. The question is: "Why can $X$ and $Y$, which are the full operators on a 1D continuous space Hamiltonian, be treated like $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ when you focus on just two bound states?"

Comment: But $X$ and $Y$ are hermitian?  Then, so is their projection onto a two-dimensional subspace, and thus can be expressed in terms of Paulis. Since you rule out $\sigma_z$, only $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ are left.  But it could also be $\sigma_x\pm\sigma_y$ -- just replace your canonical variables by new canonical variables $(X\pm Y)/\sqrt{2}$.  So the subspace follows from Hermiticity, but there is no reason to obtain specifically $\sigma_x$ or $\sigma_y$!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I see what you mean now. You could post that as an answer, particularly if you point out that the commutator between the two-level truncations of $X$ and $Y$ is always $2 i \sigma_z$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a Hermitian operator $X$, and denote by $x$ its projection to the two-dimensional subspace. Then, $x$ is Hermitian as well.  If you assume that the diagonal is zero (e.g. because you shift the energy + choose a rotating frame accordingly), then $x$ is of the form $x=\alpha_x\sigma_x+\beta_x\sigma_y$ with real $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The same is true for the projection of $Y$, $y=\alpha_y\sigma_x+\beta_y\sigma_y$.

Note that we cannot say that $x=\sigma_x$, as can be seen by changing to a different canonical basis such as $(X\pm Y)/\sqrt{2}$ (which gives $x,y\propto\sigma_x\pm\sigma_y$).

In particular, note that $[x,y]$ is a sum of commutators of $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$, i.e., it is proportional to $i\sigma_z$ (with a real prefactor).

Note that we have not used that $X$ and $Y$ are a conjugate pair. An open question is whether this would imply that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal (i.e., $\alpha_x\alpha_y+\beta_x\beta_y=0$).

Comment: I think the fact that $[X,Y]=i$ allows a stronger statement.

Comment: @DanielSank As long as you insist that you can ignore the diagonal, there will be nothing more you can say.  After all, $\sigma_z$ is no special, and then we can find a rotated basis in which the contribution in the $x$-$y$ plane is whatever you want. (I certainly also disagree with the fact that you can choose the diagonal zero for *both* $X$ and $Y$!)

Comment: Doesn't the commutator of $X$ and $Y$ at least tell you that $\alpha_x \beta_y - \beta_x \alpha_y = 1$?

Comment: @DanielSank The problem is that the commutator of the projected operators is *not* the projection of the commutator. Denote by $V$ the projection, then you are looking at $[x,y]=[VXV^\dagger,VYV^\dagger]=V(X\Pi Y-Y\Pi X)V^\dagger$, where $\Pi=V^\dagger V$.  It does thus not reduce to the commutator of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Good question,

hopefully this won't backfire since I didn't do any math to check this... but try the commutator of $[H_{x},H_{y}]$ before your 'represented as' notation (that is, in matrix form), and you should see they don't commute, hopefully in a similar way to $\sigma_{x}$ and $\sigma_{y}$.  This should be a result of your given info about $[X,Y]$.

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Indeed $[H_x, H_y] \neq 0$ (it is in fact proportional to $i$), but I don't see how that helps. I mean, I'm sure this is related but I don't see the answer.